# cannot install ros packages by command line

Tags: ros, build-from-source, rospackage, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had the ROS groovy run on Gumstix Overo but I have trouble in installing ros packages with command line.

I want to install camera1394 so I type in sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-camera1394, however following error appears:

```
root@linaro-alip:~# sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-camera1394
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-camera1394
```

Then I try to update the package list, and this is output of sudo apt-get update:

```
root@linaro-alip:~# sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg          
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                             
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise InRelease                             
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                 
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main armhf Packages              
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe armhf Packages          
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main armhf Packages             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

The output seems shorter than what I get from Ubuntu on my computer:

```
adrian@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for adrian: 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]           
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]          
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [219 kB]       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                      
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise InRelease                                  
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [5,109B]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [77.6 kB]  
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release.gpg                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [4,737 B]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [494 kB] 
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release                                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [62.8 kB]      
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise/main i386 Packages                         
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [1,950 B]
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main TranslationIndex                      
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [20.0 kB]  
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1,379 B]                      
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [233 kB]                                                        
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [9,501 B]                                                
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [178 kB]                                                     
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [3,968 B]                                                   
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [64.2 kB]                                                      
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [10.4 kB]                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                                                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                                                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                                                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources                                                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources                                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources                                                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages                                                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex                                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex                                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex                                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                                            
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,366 B]                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en                                          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                                                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en 
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en
Fetched 1,488 kB in 4s (362 kB/s)                 
Reading package lists... Done
```

Anyone knows why that happened? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54282/cannot-install-ros-packages-by-command-line/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you have Groovy installed? All those ros-groovy-* packages will not work for ARM. You will have to compile the packages from source the same way groovy itself was installed

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-04**:
I followed this link  http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=ROS  to install the Groovy.   So I need to download from source and compile it for every ros-groovy packages?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-05**:
Yes. Willow Garage is not currently providing ARM binaries for ROS releases.